# First and Last Row_Number for each partition

Tags: sql-server

I have this query that works great at retrieving my the first [Last Name] associated to the earliest [Pay Begin Period] for each partition.  However, I would now like to get the last [Last Name].  How can I do this?

```
SELECT PR.SSN as SSN, 
MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN PR.[Last Name] END) as [Last Name],
MIN(PR.Address) as [Address], 
MIN(PR.City) as [City], 
MIN(PR.State) as [State], 
MIN(PR.Zip) as [Zip],
MIN(cast(PR.[Pay Begin Period] as date)) as [Pay Begin Period],
MAX(cast(PR.[Pay End Period] as date)) as [Pay End Period],
FROM (SELECT pr.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PR.SSN ORDER BY [Pay Begin Period]) 
         as seqnum
      FROM Payroll.dbo.[Table1] PR
 ) pr
WHERE (cast(PR.[Pay Begin Period] as date) > '1/1/2013' AND
    cast(PR.[Pay End Period] as date) < '12/31/2013')
GROUP BY PR.SSN;
```

Here is my attempt, that obviously does not work:

```
SELECT PR.SSN as SSN, 
MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN PR.[Last Name] END) as [Earliest Last Name],
MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = MAX(seqnum) THEN PR.[Last Name] END) as [Latest Last Name],
MIN(PR.Address) as [Address], 
MIN(PR.City) as [City], 
MIN(PR.State) as [State], 
MIN(PR.Zip) as [Zip],
MIN(cast(PR.[Pay Begin Period] as date)) as [Pay Begin Period],
MAX(cast(PR.[Pay End Period] as date)) as [Pay End Period],
FROM (SELECT pr.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PR.SSN ORDER BY [Pay Begin Period]) 
         as seqnum
      FROM Payroll.dbo.[Table1] PR
 ) pr
WHERE (cast(PR.[Pay Begin Period] as date) > '1/1/2013' AND
    cast(PR.[Pay End Period] as date) < '12/31/2013')
GROUP BY PR.SSN;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (works in SQL Server 2012+):

```
SELECT PR.SSN as SSN, 
MAX([Earliest Last Name]),
MAX([Latest Last Name]),
MIN(PR.Address) as [Address], 
MIN(PR.City) as [City], 
MIN(PR.State) as [State], 
MIN(PR.Zip) as [Zip],
MIN(cast(PR.[Pay Begin Period] as date)) as [Pay Begin Period],
MAX(cast(PR.[Pay End Period] as date)) as [Pay End Period],
FROM (SELECT pr.*,
  first_value([Last Name]) over(partition by SSN order by [Pay Begin Period]
   range between unbounded preceding  and current row) as [Earliest Last Name],
  last_value([Last Name]) over(partition by SSN order by [Pay Begin Period]
   range between current row and unbounded following) as [Latest Last Name]
  FROM Payroll.dbo.[Table1] PR
 ) pr
WHERE (cast(PR.[Pay Begin Period] as date) > '1/1/2013' AND
    cast(PR.[Pay End Period] as date) < '12/31/2013')
GROUP BY PR.SSN;
```